# Python Tkinter daemon thread doe not terminate upon completion of the programme

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading, freeze

the problem I am facing is quite strange: I am executing a Python-programme on a raspberry pi. As it should be as user-friendly as possible, I run the programme while hiding the console. To provide the user with information that the programme is running, however, I added a Tkinter window which is opened as soon as the programme starts. Its only use is to remain open during runtime and offer a possibility of terminating the code without having to deal with the console or the task manager. As the windows should automatically close upon completion of the programme, I run it in a daemon thread.

The following pieces of code illustrate my problem.

This is the relevant code in the main file.

```
import threading

import Background_Window # python file containing the code of the status window 

t1 = threading.Thread(target=Background_Window.Background_Status_Window)    
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()

# other code
```

And this is how my status window looks like.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import signal

def Background_Status_Window():
    
    def disable_event():                
        def yes_button():
            child_prompt.destroy()
            root.destroy()
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

        def no_button():
            child_prompt.destroy()
        
        child_prompt = Toplevel(root)
        child_prompt.title("Warning")
        Warning_message = Label(child_prompt, text='Do you really want to close this window?')
        Warning_message.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
        button3 = Button(child_prompt, text="Yes", command=yes_button)
        button3.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)
        button4 = Button(child_prompt, text="No", command=no_button)
        button4.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)


    root = Tk()

    # entry widget
    Info_Text = Label(root, text='The programme is running. \n If you need to terminate it, close this window.')
    Info_Text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    # wait until window is closed
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)
    root.mainloop()
```

Interestingly, my minimum working examples on Windows work. On the raspberry pi, however, when the code of the main file has finished, the status window freezes. It cannot be closed anymore but with the task manager or a keyboard interrupt.

I have already examined when the problem arises. The status windo works perfectly fine until the last line of code in the main file has been executed. Until then it still responds to the user terminating the programme. This leads me to the conclusion that the problem must emerge when python tries to terminate the daemon thread.

I do not receive any errors in the terminal in the end of the programme. it just seems to continue with its loop.

Is anything wrong with my code?

Best
Scaty

Comment: I still have no idea how my problem could be solved using threads. Instead, I have replaced the subtread with a subprocess using Python's multiprocessing. `t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Background_Window.Background_Status_Window)`. This subprocess can finally be terminated with `t1.terminate()` and the resources released `t1.join()` to avoid a zombie. The last step was to adjust the line of code adding the interrupt functionality. Instead of `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)` I resorted to `os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)` (don't forget the double p). This solved the issue.